# Python multiprocessing and use of static methods

Tags: python, multithreading, static, multiprocessing, static-methods

We have an application running multiple worker processes connected by a multiprocessing queue.

In order to take care about the DB connections and possible errors we build a static class taking care of establishing the connection and handling errors.

An extract:

```
class DBConnector:


mysqlhost = "localhost"

mySQLConnections = dict()

@staticmethod
def getWaitingTime():
    return DBConnector.time_to_wait_after_failure

@staticmethod
def getRetries():
    return DBConnector.retries

@staticmethod
def getMySQLDB(database, user, pwd):
    '''return only new connection if no connection for this db, this user (and this thread) exists'''

    dbuserkey = database+user

    if dbuserkey in DBConnector.mySQLConnections:

        print "returning stored connection for "+dbuserkey
        pprint(DBConnector.mySQLConnections)
        return DBConnector.mySQLConnections[dbuserkey]

    else:
        print "returning new connection for "+dbuserkey
        pprint(DBConnector.mySQLConnections)
        mySQLConn = MySQLConnection(DBConnector.mysqlhost, database, user, pwd, DBConnector.retries, DBConnector.time_to_wait_after_failure)
        DBConnector.mySQLConnections[dbuserkey] = mySQLConn
        return mySQLConn
```

We had in mind that every worker process now uses this static methods to get a DB connection and ran into strange problems.

We expected that when we start 10 Workers which call the static methods that there will be 10 different database connections. But instead there was a non deterministic behaviour resulting in various number of connections sometimes 3 different or 7 different ones.

I call it "pseudo" instances of the class holding the static method.

Is this behavior normal ? Or is it a bug or someting ?

Comment: Need to see more code to say for sure, but: the static method means that once you have made a given connection, you won't make it again.  The `multiprocessing` module means that at some point your process will "fork" (on a Unix-like system anyway), copying the static setup.  If the forks all happen *before* the connections, you'd get 10 connections as expected; if they all happen *after*, you'd get just 1 (shared across all fork-ees); if they happen in between, you'd get something in between.

Comment: Thx you so much your explaination of the "forking" already explains a lot what happend, since we are working with ubuntu 12.04 LTS. So our assumptions that each process has an "isolated static instance" was wrong because of the "copy" at some point. Right now we are moving away from the static version to give every work an instance of the DB Connector which should solve our problems.